# XPS printing: lost fonts on Lexmark printers

Tags: printing, server-side, xps

I've developed a web service for printing (C# MVC 4) that creates XPS documents and then prints them via various printer servers (MS) to various print queues. This all works fine against Sharp print queues, but all font data is lost when printing to Lexmarks although the font sizes remain correct. The XPS documents all present correctly when viewed in an XPS viewer, and when printed out via the viewer to the Lexmarks via the print server work properly. The fonts are on the print servers, the Sharp queues are on the same print servers as the Lexmarks and the fonts are all specified in the XPS documents. Changing the Lexmark printer settings, drivers etc appears to make no difference.

The only pertinent question (from a year ago) on here, said the MS solution was to turn off the print spooler when doing server side printing due to a font conversion bug.

I know this is a pretty vague question, but if anyone has been through this pain and has any tips on how to resolve this I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I've been looking for a solution to this for a while, it isn't just Lexmark drivers, I have seen the same thing with other printers. It does seem to be related to printing from a Windows service. It seems to be fixed in the v4 drivers (XPS based) so I'm guessing MS aren't going to do anything about it but just wait for the printer manufacturers to migrate their drivers to the latest specs.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's not much to go on, but I suspect three things:

1. The XPS document you are producing references fonts without embedding them
2. The Lexmark print drivers on your server are XPS drivers
3. The fonts are not installed on the printers themselves.

Assuming I'm right, changing any of these three facts *should* rectify the situation, though I make no guarantees about #3.

The reason this is happening is that the fonts are not used until the XPS is rasterized - that is converted into raw image data. I suspect that in the Lexmark case, this is occurring on the device, while in the Sharp case, it is occurring on the print server. This is supported by the fact that printing the XPS document from the XPS viewer works correctly, since this causes the rasterization to occur on the machine where the viewer is running.

Using a non-XPS driver on the print server will cause a bit of a performance hit. The print server will effectively be converting XPS to GDI, which the non-XPS driver will then convert to another PDL, such as PostScript or PCL. I suspect that this is the case with the Sharp drivers, though it may also be that the Sharp driver is an XPS driver that performs the rasterization on the host.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, pointers and sense. I'm investigating this today, stripping everything down to basics and your answer gives me the areas to target.

Comment: According to the spec XPS document must contain all the referenced resources including fonts, if it doesn't then it isn't a valid XPS document.

Answer (score 1):

OK..after a lot of testing the following was noted (and may be of help to others).

In answer to the above questions..
1) embedded fonts confirmed and used MS official test XPS files.This did not help.
2) Lexmark driver used was winprint > RAW. changing this didn't help.
2) Fonts are installed on the printer

Tests
1) new print server, printing directly to a sharp printer. Problem appeared in that fonts were lost. The resolution to this was to change the spooler settings to print only after all documents were printed. The problem vanished, however I didn't want to rely on people configuring printers which requires specialist settings, so I rejected that. This is a client's network and I have no control over it.

2)printed to existing web service (using user impersonation) on print server to Sharp queues to confirm that this still worked. Confirmed.

3)Printed to existing web service (using user impersonation) on the print server to Lexmark queues and this still failed and the fonts were lost.

4) Printed from 2 separate IIS boxes to the print server to the Lexmark queues (using a domain app pool identity account) and this now worked correctly (in c# new printserver(\printerservername)) in that the Lexmarks printed correctly.

5)Printed to existing web service (using the domain app pool identity account) on print server to the Lexmark queues and this still failed (in c# new localprintserver()).

6)Printed to existing web service (using the domain app pool identity account) on print server to the Lexmark queues and this still failed (in c# new printserver(\printerservername))

The upshot of all this is that if you print locally the fonts are lost for some odd reason, but if you print remotely, the fonts are retained. All the servers have the same basic set up (no xps viewer etc and the domain app pool account is a service account) and the only difference I can see is the new localprintserver against new printserver(\printservername) calls. The same code was ported from machine to machine with the web config file holding the local or remote setting. All machines have IIS 7.5 .net 4.5 MVC 4 and are in the trusted zone.

So my solution will be split, non Sharp printing will be carried out on the document builder remote to the print server service and Sharp printing will be done on the print server (this is required for the Equitrac "follow me" printing) because I didn't want to use kerberos delegation. As stated it's not my domain and I could see the whole place grinding to a halt print wise over a lost spn or a kerberos failure.

Anyway, hope this helps someone.